# PHP- Mysql conditional not always evaluating the same

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have this code where it makes a simple query and then it executes various conditionals depending on the result.

The variable `$_SESSION['nombre'];` can't be wrong because the page where the value is assigned is checked previously with the database.

The variable `$_POST['evaluado'];` also can't be wrong because it is deployed from a verified list directly from the database.

Problem is that some users (not all of them) have been getting the message that displays when the conditional `mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0` is not true.

I have not been able to reproduce this error, I have run this code with the usernames and passwords that are supposedly giving this error, but it works completely fine to me, I cannot reproduce the error, but I do get screenshots of the error that is being displayed to the users.

Do you see anything in my code that could be causing that sometimes the conditional is true and sometimes it is not?

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

$evaluador=$_SESSION['nombre'];
$evaluado=$_POST['evaluado'];

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "sbp_admin", "sbp2014", "sbp_encuesta90");
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT Evaluador, Evaluado,Realizado FROM Beta WHERE Evaluador='$evaluador' AND Evaluado='$evaluado'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($evaluado==$row['Evaluado']) {
            # code...
             if($row['Realizado'] == 0){
        $_SESSION['nombre']=$evaluador;
        $_SESSION['evaluado']=$evaluado;
        //echo $evaluado;
            header('Location: evaluacion.php');
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<!DOCTYPE html>";
    echo '<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=euc-jp">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
        /* For zebra striping */
        $("table tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd-row");
        /* For cell text alignment */
        $("table td:first-child, table th:first-child").addClass("first");
        /* For removing the last border */
        $("table td:last-child, table th:last-child").addClass("last");
        $("table:last-child").addClass("last");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:1000; height:92px;margin: 0 auto;display: inline-block;"><div style="width:382; height:92px; display: inline-block;float: left;"><img src="logo.gif"></div><div style="width:328; height:41px; margin-top: 30px; display: inline-block;float: right;"><img src="logo.png"></div></div>
    <div><h1 style="float:left;">Evaluacion de Liderazgo 90&deg;</h1>
        <br><br>
        <br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <p>Ya has evaluado a esta persona, <a href="index.html">regresa</a> a la p&aacute;gina principal de nuestra encuesta de liderazgo</p>
<br><br></body>';
        }
    }
        else{
        echo "<!DOCTYPE html>";
       echo '<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=euc-jp">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
        /* For zebra striping */
        $("table tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd-row");
        /* For cell text alignment */
        $("table td:first-child, table th:first-child").addClass("first");
        /* For removing the last border */
        $("table td:last-child, table th:last-child").addClass("last");
        $("table:last-child").addClass("last");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:1000; height:92px;margin: 0 auto;display: inline-block;"><div style="width:382; height:92px; display: inline-block;float: left;"><img src="logo.gif"></div><div style="width:328; height:41px; margin-top: 30px; display: inline-block;float: right;"><img src="logo.png"></div></div>
    <div><h1 style="float:left;">Evaluacion de Liderazgo 90&deg;</h1>
        <br><br>
        <br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <p>No puedes evaluar a esta persona, <a href="index.html">regresa</a> a la p&aacute;gina principal de nuestra encuesta de liderazgo</p>
<br><br></body>';
        }
} 
}
else
{
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>";
echo '<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=euc-jp">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
        /* For zebra striping */
        $("table tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd-row");
        /* For cell text alignment */
        $("table td:first-child, table th:first-child").addClass("first");
        /* For removing the last border */
        $("table td:last-child, table th:last-child").addClass("last");
        $("table:last-child").addClass("last");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:1000; height:92px;margin: 0 auto;display: inline-block;"><div style="width:382; height:92px; display: inline-block;float: left;"><img src="logo.gif"></div><div style="width:328; height:41px; margin-top: 30px; display: inline-block;float: right;"><img src="logo.png"></div></div>
    <div><h1 style="float:left;">Evaluacion de Liderazgo 90&deg;</h1>
        <br><br>
        <br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <p>Verifica tu correo ya que el que ingresaste no esta en nuestra base de datos, <a href="index.html">regresa</a> a la p&aacute;gina principal de nuestra encuesta de liderazgo</p>
<br><br></body>';
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Add `error_log("Query failed: $sql")` to the `else` clause. Then when a user reports a failure, check your PHP log for the message, so you can see what query it was running.

Comment: A POST-Variable is sent by the client, and i don't see any verification of it in your code. So where and how does it get verified against the database?

Comment: hi the that POST-value is being sent from a list that of radio-buttons on the the previous page. That list is being printed directly from a query to the database that checks for the fields that match the user,so if it exists om that list it is because it was in the database. I will add the code of the previous page so that you can see what I mean as soon as I get to my laptop. Other thing that is giving me a hard time is that when I try the code with the user data, I do not get that error. I am trying a solution to the error log diagnostic suggested above, but users have not logged in yet.

Answer (score 0):

If that is not true, it means that the query returned 0 rows.

Are you completely sure that there exists at least one row to return for every possible pair of `Evaluador`and `Evaluado`?

You can also check if there is an error in the query adding this condition:

```
...
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (!$result) {
   // Display error and store the pair of inputs for debugging
}
else if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
...
```

Comment: Hi Alvaro, yes those values must exist because in previous page those ￼values are previously used, they are stored to be used in this .php... checking the error is part of the problem I have, because when I test it, it doesn't show any problem,in other words I access the site and the query does not return 0 ,the php executes smoothly, the user is the one that is having the problem but he is not physically available for me to go and check what he is doing.

Comment: The code seems good for me, I would go ahead with adding the `if (!$result) { ... }` to check if the problem is that the query is not executed properly.